# How to select a string between the characters

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace, regexp-substr

If my columns(attribute9) contains the field as `Pika~Chu~(040)-121-12334~pika78@pika.com` the how can I extract the values like

```
 contact = Pika Chu
 phone_nbr = (040)-121-12334
 email = pika78@pika.com
```

I had written the code like

```
regexp_replace(attribute9, '[^()[:digit:]- ]', '')       phone_nbr,
regexp_substr (attribute9,'[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}') email,
replace(SUBSTR (attribute9 ,0,(INSTR (attribute9 , '(', -1)) - 1),'~',' ')  contact
```

Here in phone_nbr I am getting all the digits that were in email(i.e 78) too..How can I extract just between the values (~,~)

Comment: regexp_replace(attribute9, '[^()[:digit:]- ]', '')       shipto_phone_nbr,
regexp_substr (attribute9,'[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}') email,
replace(SUBSTR (attribute9 ,0,(INSTR (attribute9 , '(', -1)) - 1),'~',' ')  shipto_contact,
















this is the code...for better understanding..please help me

Comment: Does the order always same in your column? i.e first `contact` then `phonenbr` and then `email` separated by `~`? or it can be in any order?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using a combination of the `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` as following:

> ```
> SQL> SELECT
>   2      REPLACE(SUBSTR(STR, 1, INSTR(STR, '~(') - 1), '~', ' ') AS CONTACT,
>   3      SUBSTR(STR, INSTR(STR, '~(') + 1, INSTR(STR, '~', - 1) - INSTR(STR, '~(') - 1) AS PHONE_NBR,
>   4      SUBSTR(STR, INSTR(STR, '~', - 1) + 1) AS EMAIL
>   5  FROM
>   6      (SELECT
>   7          'Pika~Chu~(040)-121-12334~pika78@pika.com' AS STR
>   8       FROM DUAL);
>
> CONTACT  PHONE_NBR       EMAIL
> -------- --------------- ---------------
> Pika Chu (040)-121-12334 pika78@pika.com
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use only `REGEXP` to get your output as below.

```
Select 'Pika~Chu~(040)-121-12334~pika78@pika.com' col,
       regexp_substr('Pika~Chu~(040)-121-12334~pika78@pika.com','(.*?)(~)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) ||' ' ||regexp_substr('Pika~Chu~(040)-121-12334~pika78@pika.com','(.*?)(~)', 1, 2, NULL, 1 ) contact,
       regexp_substr('Pika~Chu~(040)-121-12334~pika78@pika.com','(.*?)(~)', 1, 3, NULL, 1 ) phone,
       regexp_substr('Pika~Chu~(040)-121-12334~pika78@pika.com','[^~]+$') email
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select (regexp_substr(str, '^[^~]+', 1) || ' ' || regexp_substr(str, '[^~]+', 1, 2)) as contact,
       regexp_substr(str, '[^~]+', 1, 3) as phone,
       regexp_substr(str, '[^~]+', 1, 4) as email
 from (select 'Pika~Chu~(040)-121-12334~pika78@pika.com' AS STR
       from dual
      ) x;
```

In the above, the only difference in the calls is the last argument, which specifies which component of the string to extract.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f42022b507529b99824ca44f36068b42) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should fix the database design as storing multiple values in one column violates first normal form and will cause nothing but headaches.

With that out of the way, use REGEXP_SUBSTR() to split the string into it's components where followed by the delimiter or the end of the line.  Doing it this way handles NULL elements while using a consistent regex.

```
with tbl(id, attribute9) as (
  select 1, 'Pika~Chu~(040)-121-12334~pika78@pika.com' from dual union all
  select 2, 'Drowzee~~(040)-121-23445~dz78@pika.com' from dual
)
SELECT id, 
  regexp_substr(attribute9, '(.*?)(~|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) a9_firstname,
  regexp_substr(attribute9, '(.*?)(~|$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1) a9_lastname,
  regexp_substr(attribute9, '(.*?)(~|$)', 1, 3, NULL, 1) a9_phone,
  regexp_substr(attribute9, '(.*?)(~|$)', 1, 4, NULL, 1) a9_email
FROM tbl
order by id;
```